# ajax jquery caching issue in IE

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a function that connects and get sql query as results. Below function is what I have and it works perfectly fine in all other browser but IE. 
After some reading, I found out about the caching issue, so I included `cache: false,`. That didn't work. Then I added,

> `$.ajaxSetup({   cache: false });`

top of the the script, still didn't do that trick.
Here is the the complete function. Any help would be is greatly appreciated, because I don't know what am I doing wrong <strike>and I'm *this* close redirect users away from IE</strike>.

```
Check_MiceToCage = function(vGetSex,vDoWhat){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'MiceDB.cfc?method=TempTableDateToRealData&getSex='+vGetSex+'&doWhat='+vDoWhat+'&ReturnFormat=json',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {     
        if(response.DATA.length == 0){
          //$("#ResponseID").html('No Male mice' + response.DATA.length);
          alert('No Mice' +vGetSex);
        }
        else{
          //$("#ResponseID").html('Yes we have male mice' + response.DATA.length);
          alert('Yes Mice' +vGetSex);
        }
      },
      error: function(ErrorMsg) {
         console.log('Error!');
      }
  });
}
```

UPDATE:
I'm executing the above function onSubmit.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a unique parameter to your URL, like

```
url: 'MiceDB.cfc?method=TempTableDateToRealData&getSex='+vGetSex+'&doWhat='+vDoWhat+'&ReturnFormat=json&t=' + new Date().getTime() + '&r=' + Math.random() * 999999,
```

Comment: nothing in IE? or nothing in FF too? what does Firebug says - is it sending the parameters correctly?

Comment: nothing in both. just a FYI, I'm running this onSubmit, if it helps.

Comment: I didn't have `t` inside the function `Check_MiceToCage` and I changed it to what you've suggested and it works in FF now, but still no in IE.

Comment: did you make sure that you did a Hard Refresh of the page in IE (CTRL +F5) otherwise it could be caching the page and not updating the script in IE. I have found that this can sometimes cause a problem when trying to run scripts.

Comment: not sure about IE, but it might cache the time as well.. can you try just with a random number - updated answer

Comment: @ZoltanToth I tried w/ your updated answer still nothing on IE (FF works fine).

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing" - it doesn't send anything or always sends the cached request?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have more specific than saying, "nothing". I get the 'Error!'. And if I change the ErrorMsg function to `alert('Error');` , that's what I get.

Comment: try to alert/console.log the `url` you're trying to connect to and see if that's OK

Comment: Yes that works, I mean it connect ok. I get `{"COLUMNS":["TAGNO","MOUSEID","VALUEIS"],"DATA":[[656.0,1,1.0]]}`

Comment: I lost you.. if it works then what's the problem? :) Is the request still being cached?

Comment: it connects to the url ok. However in IE it skips the success function `response` and falls to `ErrorMsg`.